# Div problems using html, css, Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

In an HTML document, I have created a div. In it, I created another div, and in this inner div I put a cross sign. I want to build an event function that closes the parent div when the user clicks on the cross sign.

An example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>Div problems</title></head>
<body>
<div id="content"> 
   <div id="box1"> <img src="people.gif"/> </div> 
   <div id="box2"> <img src="camera.gif" height=30px width=30px/> </div> 
   <div id="box3"> <img src="square.gif" height=30px width=30px/> </div> 
   <div id="box4"> <img src="rectangle-image3.gif" height=30px width=30px/> </div>    
   <div id="box5"> <img src="triangle.gif" height=30px width=30px/> </div> 
   <div id="box6"> <img src="correct.gif" height=30px width=30px/> </div> 
   <div id="box7"> <img src="exit.gif" height=30px width=30px/> </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

The cross would be the "exit" image.
Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Why don't you post your HTML code, that way we can give you better advice.

Comment: I added the example code. @Ashish please modify it to better describe your own situation.

Comment: <div id="content">
 <div id="box1">
<img src="people.gif"/>
  </div>
  <div id="box2">
  <img src="camera.gif" height=30px width=30px/>
  </div>
  <div id="box3">
   <img src="square.gif" height=30px width=30px/>
  </div>
  <div id="box4">
   <img src="rectangle-image3.gif" height=30px width=30px/>
  </div>
  <div id="box5">
   <img src="triangle.gif" height=30px width=30px/>
  </div>
  <div id="box6">
   <img src="correct.gif" height=30px width=30px/>
  </div>
  <div id="box7">

<img src="exit.gif" height=30px width=30px/>
</form>

  </div>
</div>

Comment: here i created a div and inside there are seven div at the last div i want that when i should click it the parent div content should be removed

Comment: Guys i had posted my code please kindly see it

Comment: two things: first, you should edit your question (perhaps you don't have the reputation yet for that, though). Second, the relative references to the images will not load from here as they are now.

Comment: Its ok id dont care for the images and yes you are correct i dont have,

Comment: <div id="content">
 <div id="box1">

  </div>
  <div id="box2">
 
  </div>
  <div id="box3">
 
  </div>
  <div id="box4">
 
  </div>
  <div id="box5">
   
  </div>
  <div id="box6">
   
  </div>
  <div id="box7">




  </div>
</div>

Comment: now i want when i should click the  seventh div my parent div "content" should close

Comment: Ok, I added your code. Another thing would be to explain what do you mean by "close". Should the div be hidden or deleted?

Comment: After clicking the close button the parent div should be closed

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried anything so far?  Given this description, I guess just using a click event on the inner element to change the CSS of the outer element will work fine.  Here's a quick example with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#innerElement').click(function() {
    $('#outerElement').hide();
  });
});
```

This will effectively set the parent's CSS display to "none." Hiding the parent element will, of course, hide any containing elements, including the one being clicked.

Answer (score 1):

How is this idea.
HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>Div problems</title></head>
<body>
<div id="content" style="position:relative"> 
   <div id="box1"> <img src="people.gif"/> </div> 
   <div id="box2"> <img src="camera.gif" height=30px width=30px/> </div> 
   <div id="box3"> <img src="square.gif" height=30px width=30px/> </div> 
   <div id="box4"> <img src="rectangle-image3.gif" height=30px width=30px/> </div>    
   <div id="box5"> <img src="triangle.gif" height=30px width=30px/> </div> 
   <div id="box6"> <img src="correct.gif" height=30px width=30px/> </div> 
   <div id="box7" style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0" onclick="hideContent()"> <img src="exit.gif" height=30px width=30px/> </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function hideContent() {
document.getElementById('content').style.display="none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this should do it, say this is your markup:

```
<div id="parent"><div><span>CROSS SIGN</span></div></div>
```

And JQuery:

```
$('#parent span').click(function() {
             $('#parent').hide();
});
```

This should do it.

Comment: This can't be done without using something like this. HTML is for layout of pages, CSS is for styling the layout of the pages. JS or simliar languages are for creating the dynamic aspects of the page.

Comment: Yes, but there is no need to use a framework.. the `$` function is not a JS function, that's added by JQuery and similar frameworks. Same thing with the `hide()` method. This can be done without using any frameworks, directly on javascript, but your code is framework dependant... that's all I was pointing out.

Comment: your code hides the inner div, not the outer. Plus, the "#parent" moniker is wrong: the parent is the outer div, not the inner.

Comment: First of all thanks ,i am not using jquery instead i can use javascript can you help me how to close the parent div.


Thanks
Ashish Juyal

Comment: Here i want to close the parent div from the inside div,plz help

Answer (score 0):

This code shows a simplistic approach to the problem, in pure javascript. You should be able to adapt it to your particular problem.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Div problems</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                var childLink = document.getElementById('sonlink');
                childLink.onclick = function() {
                    var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
                    parent.style.display = 'none';
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>    
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="parent">Outer div
        <div id="son">Inner div <a href="#" id="sonlink">+</a></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Ashish If it worked for you, upvoting the answer would be nice :)

Comment: i dint get you what did you meant by upvoting?

Comment: @Ashish it sounds like you really need to read the FAQs of this site. voting an answer or question means clicking on the ^ or v arrows on their left to say "this is useful" or "this is not useful".

Comment: :) nevermind then. Have you read the FAQ and basic guidelines?